# How to return an html modal target view from server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, routes, modal-dialog

I want to have a button on the website that opens up a modal view using bootstrap. Like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="modalButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>
```

So this button is targeting a view called #myModal. Instead of loading the #myModal view from the client html, **I want to make an AJAX request to the server to get #myModal view** because the view will be different depending on if the user is admin or not, and that variable resides on the server.

So the request would be something like this:

```
$('#modalButton').click() -> 
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/modalFeedback",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

Then the /modalFeedback route should check if the user is admin or not, and send back the corresponding #myModal view. I am confused on how to implement this exactly, **more specifically how to return the #myModal view from the server so it opens up normally.**

If someone could help me with some pseudo-code that would be extremely helpful!

**UPDATE**

I got it working with the bootstrap remote option (see answer below), here is how I called the modal:

```
a#uservoice_tab(data-toggle="modal", href="/modalFeedback.html", data-target="#myModal")
  img(src='/img/icon-idea.png')
// You need to have #myModal element in the same place you have the button. Bootstrap injects the body into this element remotely
#myModal.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='myModalLabel', aria-hidden='true')
```

Here is the modalFeedback.html source in jade

```
.modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') ×
        h4#myModalLabel.modal-title Modal title
      .modal-body
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='button') Save changes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to be using bootstrap, it actually has this built in so that you don't have to do the ajax call yourself. Take a look at the `remote` option for [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

The content that you return simply needs to be the HTML fragment you want to be in the content of the modal.

An example of how you would return the html for the modal if you're using express is as follows (using jade as your templating engine but it could be whatever you like):

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get(
    '/modalFeedback'
    ,function(req, res, next){
        res.render('/modalFeedback.jade', { user: req.user });
    }
);
```

The template, in this case `modalFeedback.jade` would have just html in it, well a jade version of html anyway and this is the html you wish to show up in the modal. You could even instead of simply rendering the template at first do some checks if the user is admin or whatever. Depending on the check then you could choose which template to render. The key is `res.render` goes and gets the file passing it the data you provide and will return it to the browser call from the modal.

**Update**: `remote` is [deprecated](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options) since v3.3.0 and removed in v4. (This would have been better suited as a comment but is likely to be missed, hence putting it here to protect people's time in managing backward compatibility issues later)

Comment: Thanks I will look into the remote option and update the question with my results. Would the html fragment to return just be a javascript String? A really long String? What is the best way to return html fragment from javascript function?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how you would return a string, a really long string to the modal for it to show.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear and makes sense. For the bootstrap remote option, do I just put /modalFeedback route in the href tag for the button? Like so: <a data-toggle="modal" href="/modalFeedback" data-target="#myModal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

Comment: yup, that's it exactly.

Comment: Thanks I will try it tomorrow and mark your answer as correct after.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, When I click the button the screen dims but no modal is visible. I can get it to work normally without remote but I cant get it to work with the remote option! Why is it behaving this way? Check out the updated question... Thanks!

Comment: Actually I got it to work! I updated the answer, I just didn't have the remote html right

Comment: I was just writing a test case to see it for myself. Guess you saved me the trouble. Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest keep blank the modal div in the html..

```
<div id="modalbox" >
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="modalButton" data-toggle="modal"       
data-target="#myModal">
 Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Call the ajax to server and return model box html content string based on admin or else and fill it on modal button click and make modal visible ..

```
$('#modalButton').click() -> 
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","/modalFeedback",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
  document.getElementById("modalbox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}    
xmlhttp.send();
$("#modalbox").show();
```

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer, I will test this out vs bootstrap remote option. But this method should work for sure.